# How to create Unit test using Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

i am creating Unit test for one of my factory and this is first time i am creating test using Angularjs.when i run grunt test in root of my directory i get an error cannot find plugin karma-phantomjs-launcher.

code tried so far...

Factory.spec.js

```
describe('lrrDetails', function () {
        'use strict';

        var httpBackend, serviceToTest, lrrSearchModalFactory;
        beforeEach(module('thirdPartyManagementApp'));

        beforeEach(inject(function ($httpBackend, lrrDetails) {
            httpBackend = $httpBackend;
            lrrSearchModalFactory = lrrDetails;

        }));

        it('should call the API to get Lrr Details for Dialog box', function (regInventoryId) {
            httpBackend.expectGET('/third-party-management/rest/lrr/' + regInventoryId).respond(200, 'success');
            var promise = lrrSearchModalFactory.findlrrDetail();
            httpBackend.flush();
            promise.then(function (data) {
                expect(data.data).toBe('success');
            });
        });


    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have the plugin installed, by typing on the command line:

```
npm install karma-phantomjs-launcher --save-dev
```

Source: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher

Comment: Thanks i ran that command and getting an error UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE